# Python-Beautiful Soup- Parsing XML-repeated string

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I am trying to get some information from a [page](https://kith.com/collections/all/products.atom). Here is how I set it up:

```
url =str('https://kith.com/collections/all/products.atom')
r = requests.get(url)    
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml")
```

I am trying to get the 'size' for each product on this page. The price is tag as `<title>` which is located the `<variant>` tag inside the `<entry>` tag.

```
items = soup.find_all('entry')
   for item in items:
     variants=item.find_all('variant')

     for variant in variants:    
          size = variant.title.text
          print('size: '+str(size))
```

For some reasons, instead of size: 3 it prints out size:33.
When ran it the third time it prints out size:333 and so on.  Why is it repeating itself and how can I fix it?

Comment: are you trying to get `price` or `size` ?

Comment: Sorry, i am trying to get size.

Comment: I run your code above, it print without repeating.